# is there a simpler way of running terraform commands with npm or on its own, when you have multiple environments? that works on both win & linux?

Tags: terraform, command-line-interface, terraform-cloud, terraform-workspace, terraform-cli

I'm currently trying to do a basic set of infrastructure on 3 different projects via terraform cloud.

I have 3 workspaces:

- development
- staging
- production

with their own variables defined for service accounts and all of that.

I want -- for the time being at least -- to interact with the infrastructure via CLI from my local machine. The issue is I have to define the workspace in my`backend` as a hardcoded string so I can't put in a variable.

I found a clever way around it using `dev.hcl` files which contain data about the backend so I can simply run:

```
terraform -chdir=infrastructure init -backend-config="dev.hcl"
```

It works but it is quite a lot to type whenever I want to run init/plan/apply so I'm looking for a simpler way to streamline this.

I've tried creating scripts in the root `package.json` and dynamically change `dev` to an argument passed to the CLI, unfortunately this doesn't work consistently across windows and linux and because of the order of commands needs to be exact with terraform CLI, I'm out of options.

The current scripts I have in package.json:

```json
"tf-init-dev": "terraform -chdir=infrastructure init -backend-config=\"dev.hcl\"",
"tf-plan-dev": "terraform -chdir=infrastructure plan -backend-config=\"dev.hcl\"",
"tf-apply-dev": "terraform -chdir=infrastructure apply -backend-config=\"dev.hcl\"",
"tf-init-stage": "terraform -chdir=infrastructure init -backend-config=\"stage.hcl\"",
"tf-plan-stage": "terraform -chdir=infrastructure plan -backend-config=\"stage.hcl\"",
"tf-apply-stage": "terraform -chdir=infrastructure apply -backend-config=\"stage.hcl\"",
"tf-init-prod": "terraform -chdir=infrastructure init -backend-config=\"prod.hcl\"",
"tf-plan-prod": "terraform -chdir=infrastructure plan -backend-config=\"prod.hcl\"",
"tf-apply-prod": "terraform -chdir=infrastructure apply -backend-config=\"prod.hcl\"",
```

and I imagine I'll be adding more commonly used ones as the project develops.

Is there a better way of tackling this use case?

Comment: Usually I would suggest using a CI/CD, where you would write the command once and pass the arguments depending on the environment, but I don't know what is your use case.

Comment: that's the plan once we do most of the initial development, during which I'll be needing to run apply hundreds of times to get the right result.

Comment: Have you tried mapping the CLI workspaces to the TF Cloud workspaces such that the `workspace` subcommand also interacts with the API? It is possible to do that.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have not, never heard of that even being a possibility, any chance you have a link to some documentation about it? google searching is failing me around this topic, thank you.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/cli/workspaces#interactions-with-terraform-cloud-workspaces

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank you but sadly that doesn't do what I expected but rather the exact same thing -- targeting 1 single workspace that has all 3 static tags defined. 

I'd have to manually change the tag name to whatever environment I want to interact with at any given time, regardless of what 'local' workspace I'm part of. 

I've created another SO thread describing the issue.

Comment: @MattSchuchard alright so it seems the correct usage is: 

tag with "main" all 3 workspaces, then switch between local workspaces when you want to act as that workspace and the commands will work on the remote workspace with the same name, if you post it as the answer I'd be happy to mark it as the correct one to help people in the future interested in the same use case.

Thanks.

Comment: @SebastianG It kind of sounds like you solved your own question and not me.

Comment: fair enough, I mean it was through the help of two people on two different questions pointing me in the right direction, I find it rare for someone to be able to provide the straight up answer in most cases so this is as close as it gets